# Elfshadows and attuned items

Tags: dnd-5e, attunement, intelligent-magic-items

So I'm aware that creatures can attune to items. Familiars and the like are great options for having attuned items being used when your slots are full.

My character got a moonblade with the elfshadow property:

> You can use an action to call forth an elfshadow, provided that you don't already have one serving you. The elfshadow appears in an unoccupied space within 120 feet of you. It uses the statistics for a shadow, except it is neutral, immune to effects that turn undead, and doesn't create new shadows. You control this creature, deciding how it acts and moves. It remains until it drops to 0 hit points or you dismiss it as an action.  *~DMG 217*

The shadow should easily qualify as something that can attune items. My question is, what happens when it dies or is dismissed? Would the items return to the sword with it, and come out again the next time it is summoned? Would they fall to the ground and require re-attuning on resummon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Items fall to the ground and they need re-attunement.**

The item falls to the ground as there is no text indicating the elfshadow carrying the items along with it to the sword. In fact, the elfshadow doesn't come out from the sword; it simply appears when summoned and disappears when killed or dismissed.

On Dmg page 136 it is stated that:

> A creature's attunement to an item ends if the creature no longer satisfies the prerequisites for attunement, if the item has been more than 100 feet away for at least 24 hours, if the creature dies, or if another creature attunes to the item. A creature can also voluntarily end attunement by spending another short rest focused on the item, unless the item is cursed.

Also the text does not state anything on the elfshadow being the same creature upon resummoning, so the new elfshadow must re-attune on resummon.